# Multiplying list<int> with number in C#

Tags: c#

Is the only way you can multiply an integer list in C# with a value, by using a loop through the items?
I have been searching for ways to avoid loops, but with no luck.
I know in Python, for example you do not have to loop through a list to do this, so I was wondering if there is any way in C# as well to achieve the following:

```
  List<int> myList = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3 };
  
  int mult = 5;

  foreach(int i in myList)
     mult = mult * i;
```

Comment: Even Python is looping, it might just not be so apparent.

Comment: Why are you trying to avoid loops? Even if Python doesn't make the loop apparent to you, it will still have to loop internally to achieve what you want.

Comment: I suggest you read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/

Comment: There is LINQ, it does not look like you are using loop structure but internally it loops. I am confidently say there is no way to achieve this without loop. `myList.ForEach(i => mul *= i)`. Also performance-wise it's worse.

Comment: @DavidG sure I assume it still loops "under the hood", yet I am trying to understand if there is something similar in C# as well, which avoids writing any loops

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use LINQ's [`Aggregate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.aggregate?view=net-6.0#System_Linq_Enumerable_Aggregate__2_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0____1_System_Func___1___0___1__) to do this:

```cs
List<int> myList = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3 };
int mult = myList.Aggregate(5, (cur, val) => cur * val);
Console.WriteLine(mult); // prints 30
```

But note that this still uses a loop internally. Python will also use a list internally, even if it isn't apparent to you.

Comment: For OP's case (List<T>), I think `ForEach` may be simpler to write.

Comment: @LukeVo Personally, I prefer this, but I agree that `.ForEach` also works equally well.

Comment: @LukeVo IMO `ForEach` is awful and I wish it was never introduced into the language.

Comment: @DavidG can you elaborate? I think it's awesome and a bit salty they didn't add it into LINQ and only `List<T>`s have them.

Comment: @Luke I think it makes sense that `.ForEach` doesn't exist in LINQ as isn't really a query method.

Comment: @LukeVo Eric Lippert discusses the reasons here: https://ericlippert.com/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach/